# remove every thing from a line in Perl up to a specific word

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I need to remove every thing from a line in Perl up to a specific word .
suppose i have these 3 lines

```
Helicobacter Contig1
Helicobacter contig1
Helicobacter .Contig1
```

I want to have contig1 or Contig 1

I have tried

```
$test=s/^(.*?)^(contig|Contig)//g;
```

but it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: You won't need the 'g' modifier; you can only have one match of everything between the beginning of the line and [cC]ontig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the second `^`

your regex should be `s/^(.*?)(?=contig|Contig)//g;`

the `.*?` is non-greedy, so it will stop as soon as it can (i.e when it sees contig or Contig). you could also use the `\i` modifier to make the match case insensitive, so you don't have to check for two different strings.

Comment: It removes the "contig" ,i want to remove every thing from beginning of the line up to contig